# SegNet: Why is training accuracy high but validation accuracy low?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I try to train a SegNet-Basic implemented in Keras on the [Berkeley DeepDrive](https://deepdrive.berkeley.edu/) dataset. But after training the validation accuracy settles at about 50-60% while the training accuracy climbes to over 90%.

I tried using different optimizers and picture sizes. the masks of the dataset come as greyscale image and i split them according to the [provided labels](https://github.com/ucbdrive/bdd-data/blob/master/bdd_data/label.py) into a numpy array with [img_height,img_width,num_classes] per picture.

My SegNet_Basic implementation looks as follows: the _encode and _decode functions are implementations of the Unpool with indices that the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.00561) states.

```py
def SegNet_Basic(n_labels,input_shape= (480,352,3)):
    kernel = 3
    filter_size = 64
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

    c1 = Conv2D(filter_size, (3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(inputs)
    c1 = BatchNormalization()(c1)

    pool_1, mask_1 = _encode(c1)

    c2 = Dropout(0.2)(pool_1)
    c2 = Conv2D(128, (3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(c2)
    c2 = BatchNormalization()(c2)

    pool_2, mask_2 = _encode(c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(256, (3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_2)
    c3 = BatchNormalization()(c3)

    pool_3, mask_3 = _encode(c3)

    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(pool_3)
    c4 = Conv2D(512, (3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(c4)
    c4 = BatchNormalization()(c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same')(c4)
    c5 = BatchNormalization()(c5)

    c6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c5)
    unpool_1 = _decode(c6,mask_3)

    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(unpool_1)
    c6 = Conv2D(256, (3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(c6)
    c6 = BatchNormalization()(c6)

    c7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c6)
    unpool_2 = _decode(c7,mask_2)

    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(unpool_2)
    c7 = Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation='relu',padding='same')(c7)
    c7 = BatchNormalization()(c7)

    c8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c7)
    unpool_3 = _decode(c8,mask_1)

    c8 = Conv2D(filter_size,(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(unpool_3)
    c8 = BatchNormalization()(c8)
    output = Conv2D(n_labels, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c8)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], output=[output], name='SegNet_Basic')

    return model
```

Im using a picture size of (480,352) as i cant use bigger sizes because my laptop cant handle them on the gpu. I also see, that classes like sky and trees get recognized pretty good as seen in the first picture that i added, but the accuracy of the other classes are pretty horrible.

I can also provide other parts of my code if it is needed!

Thank you for any Help in advance!!

[predicted output per class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7tAs.png)

[model accuracy after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDmKi.png)

[model loss after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF4rK.png)

[Output of a training picture after training 100 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOENi.png)

Comment: What a prime example of overfitting :-) How big are your minibatches?

Comment: are you sure its overfitting? Because if i do the predict with a picture of the trainingsset i also get a pretty bad result - see the last picture attached.

My batch size is 1 because if i increase it, my Laptop runs out of memory (8GB)...

Comment: That's a single example, see the train/test loss/accuracy trends. Test stalls pretty soon while train keeps improving indefinitely. However, with batch size 1, BatchNorm will be... identity in the best case. Get rid of it and strengthen dropout instead.

Comment: Ohh.. i never thought BatchNorm could be the problem... I will let it run without the BachNorms and with some more Dropouts! Lets see! 

and thanks for the heads up! I was searching for something like that! I will definitely try that out!! I heard that you now even can use TPUs instead of GPUs with that!